# rails 4 fetch custom column after query execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following query

```
@products = Product.where category_id: id
```

Consider I have following columns

1. id
2. category_id
3. slug

After executing I need to get the `id` of the product with the `slug` name `test` alone. Need to fetch just with `limit 1`. Is it possible. If yes how can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to keep the rest of `@products`?

If so:

```
@products = Product.where(category_id: id)
@the_product = @products.find { |p| p.slug == 'test' }
# Note: This will iterate over objects in memory. Depending on 
# how many products you have per category, it may be more efficient 
# to simply make another query to the database, as with the code below.
```

If not:

```
@products = Product.where(category_id: id, slug: 'test').limit(1)
```